# Changing ui from thread

Tags: android

I know there were similiar question, but my problem slightly different
i have such code

```
 Thread t = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            while(!running) {
                if(gpstracker.canGetLocation()) {
                    double lon = gpstracker.getLongitude();
                    double lat = gpstracker.getLatitude();
                    now = new LatLng(lat,lon);
                    if(change(now)==1)
                        running = true;
                    else
                        ;
                }
                else {
                    gpstracker.showSettingsAlert();
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

in `change(now)` i'm changin ui so my question is how can i change UI from my thread? I have read about handler od async task but i dont think they are ok in this situation, or maybe i dont know how i can use them, any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this activity method:

```
YourActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run(){ 
      //Your awesome code here

  }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

well in the change now you can do

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
    // your ui code here

    }
});
```