# How do I run code on a UI thread without an activity reference?

Tags: android, multithreading, ui-thread, okhttp

I need to update UI in OKHttp's request callbacks, the callbacks run in worker thread by default. How can I run them in UI thread?

I know of activity.runOnUIThread(), but I don't have any references to any activity in the callbacks.

Comment: check this [answer by elltz](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28226320/changing-ui-from-thread/28226646#28226646)  _don't forget to honor it_ :)

Comment: It works. I have upvoted your answer in that thread, thanks!